# Phase margin for a system (design of PD controller)

Tags: control, phase, bode-plot, phase-margin

I have a system with the following transfer function:

\$G(s)=\cfrac{20}{s^2+s+20K_f}\$

where \$K_f=1.75\$

I want to use a PD controller and I want obtain a phase margin of 35 degrees. I need to determine the parameters (\$K_p \text{ and } K_D\$) for the PD controller.

I made a Bode plot in Scilab for G(s):

[image]

As I want a phase margin of -10º, I would have to see the \$f_0\$ for which I have a phase of \$\phi=-10-180=-190º\$, but with -190º the system is unstable.

I can not determine \$f_0\$ from the Bode Plot, because the graph only reaches -180º. How can I design the PD controller for this system?

Comment: You want it to be an oscillator then?

Comment: @Andyaka No, I want to know if I can design a PD controller in order to have the entire system (with controller) with 35º phase margin.

Comment: I would resort to classical pole-zero placement then convert them into \$k_p\$ and \$k_d\$ parameters. However, before you do this, you have to select a crossover frequency \$f_c\$ and extract the magnitude and phase at this point from your Bode plot. Then you'll know how much gain (or attenuation) and phase boost are needed at \$f_c\$ to satisfy your phase margin design. You can have a look at a seminar I taught at APEC some time ago, I showed how to match PID parameters with poles and zeroes: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf

Comment: @CarmenGonzález why are you saying you want a phase margin of -10 if in fact you want a phase margin of +35? You currently have a PM of about 20 deg so what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @Andyaka I want a phase margin of 35º with the controller. Since the controller increases 45 degrees in the phase for high frequencies, so I want to obtain a "phase margin" for the system without controller of -10º (35º-45º). In summary, I want a phase margin of 35º for the system with the controller. I need to find Kp and Kd for the controller.

Comment: Why not live with the current PM of circa +23 degrees (a little bit peaky) and you'll know that when you loop it with the PD controller the new PM will be +(23 + 45) = +68 degrees and very nice IMHO. I'm saying this because you seem to be fixated on achieving a precise value of PM with no apparent reasoning behind this precision.

Comment: @Andyaka I want 35º of phase margin because that is what the prof wants us to do in the exercise.

Comment: If the controller *increases 45 degrees in the phase at high frequencies* then what use will adjusting Kp and Kd be? Something has to give; either you *can* adjust the k values and get less phase shift or you *can't* and you are stuck. Which is it?

Comment: 1. you need to derive the system equation which include the controler. 2. once you have H(s), you can set the desired phase margin by ajusting your gains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to compensate the plant whose transfer function is given so that once compensated you have a phase margin of 35°. The plant transfer function is \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1}{\tau_2s^2+\tau_1s+1}\$ with \$H_0=\frac{1}{k_f}\$, \$\tau_1=\frac{1}{20k_f}s\$ and \$\tau_2=\frac{1}{20k_f}s^2\$. The plot I got from Mathcad is this one and matches yours:

[image]

Then, you need to pick a crossover frequency \$f_c\$ at which you will measure the open-loop phase margin of 35°. Let's take \$f_c=10\;Hz\$. What is the attenuation of the plant at \$f_c\$ and what is its phase?

[image]

From these values, calculate the needed phase boost from the inverting compensator to meet the 35° design criteria and deduce the position of the zero:

[image]

Determine what the \$k_p\$ coefficient should be based on the zero position and plot the open-loop gain \$T(s)\$:

[image]

The crossover frequency is 10 Hz as arbitrarily selected and the phase margin is 35°. The compensator transfer function is \$G_1(s)\$ in the picture. Is this what you wanted to see?